# Weird IEnumerable behavior in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach, iterator, ienumerable, yield-return

I have the following method:

```
public IEnumerable<object> GetParameters(Context context)
{
    yield return new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
}
```

When I loop through this enumeration:

```
foreach (var parameter in GetParameters())
{
    // Do something here with parameter
}
```

I expect the parameter to be `1` at the first loop, `2` at the second and `3` and the third but this is not the case :(

[image]

`parameter` is an array that contains all values!

What am I missing here??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your method to

```
public IEnumerable GetParameters(Context context)
{
    return new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
}
```

or

```
public IEnumerable GetParameters(Context context)
{
    yield return 1;
    yield return 2;
    yield return 3;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're returning a single instance of the enumerable array.

You want:

```
yield return 1;
yield return 2;
yield return 3;
```

Answer (score 3):

`yield return` returns a single object.  You seem to be execting something like a `yield foreach` in which it yields each item in the collection.  (This is a frequently requested feature that doesn't exist.)

You just need to do something like:

```
foreach(int i in new[]{1, 2, 3})
  yield return i;
```

It's also best to use a strongly typed `IEnumerable` where possible, in this case it would be `IEnumerable<int>`.  If you did that then you'd be getting a compile time error when you try to yield a collection rather than unexpected runtime behavior.